# Why calendar week number updates on Monday at 3 a.m., but not at midnight?

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

I am using `iso_week.h` from [howardhinnant.github.io/iso_week.html](http://howardhinnant.github.io/iso_week.html) to calculate the week number for a given date. However, it looks that it updates the week number on Monday at 3 a.m., instead of midnight.

For example code like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "iso_week.h"

int main() {
    using namespace iso_week;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    /* Assume we have two time points:
     * tp1 corresponds: Monday July 15 02:50:00 2019
     * tp2 corresponds: Monday July 15 03:00:00 2019
     */
    // Floor time points to convert to the sys_days:
    auto tp1_sys = floor<days>(tp1);
    auto tp2_sys = floor<days>(tp2);
    // Convert from sys_days to iso_week::year_weeknum_weekday format
    auto yww1 = year_weeknum_weekday{tp1_sys};
    auto yww2 = year_weeknum_weekday{tp2_sys};
    // Print corresponding week number of the year
    std::cout << "Week of yww1 is: " << yww1.weeknum() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Week of yww2 is: " << yww2.weeknum() << std::endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
Week of yww1 is: W28
Week of yww2 is: W29
```

Why is this being done?

Comment: Can you show `tp1` and `tp2` values in code?

Comment: I had a problem similar to that once.  It turned out to be daylight savings time was built into the crtl.

Comment: @KorelK @HowardHinnant Now I see my problem. Both tp1 and tp2 are `std::chrono::system_clock` time points.

Comment: Right, I just noticed your comment about `sys_days`.  Would you like me to show an answer involving tz.h that will convert the time points to your local time zone prior to giving them to iso_week?

Comment: @HowardHinnant This would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first I didn't notice your comment:

```
// Floor time points to convert to the sys_days:
```

This means that `tp1` and `tp2` are based on `system_clock`.  And `system_clock` models UTC.

You can use the tz.h header (tz.cpp source) to get your current time zone, convert the UTC time points to local time points, and then feed them to `year_weeknum_weekday`.  This will define the start of the day as your local midnight instead of midnight UTC.

This would look something like:

```
#include "date/iso_week.h"
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace iso_week;
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto tp1 = floor<seconds>(system_clock::now());
    zoned_seconds zt{current_zone(), tp1};
    auto tp1_local = floor<days>(zt.get_local_time());
    auto yww1 = year_weeknum_weekday{tp1_local};
    std::cout << "Week of yww1 is: " << yww1.weeknum() << std::endl;
}
```

`current_zone()` queries your computer for its current local time zone setting.  If you prefer some other time zone, you can just replace `current_zone()` with the time zone name:

```
zoned_seconds zt{"Europe/Athens", tp1};
```

If you want to work in a precision finer than seconds, `zoned_seconds` is just a type alias for `zoned_time<seconds>`.  So use whatever precision you need (e.g. `zoned_time<milliseconds>`).

Use of tz.h does require [some installation](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation).  It is not header only.

Answer (score 1):

Could this have something to do with your time zone? I know a lot of businesses are located on the east coast and "iso_week.h" could be based on that time, meaning it could be running at midnight and it just tells you that it is running at 3am. If this is not the case would it be wrong to just run the program at 9pm?